# How to fill only predefined area on canvas using gesture

Tags: android, gesture, android-gesture

I my app I have some shapes , I want to fill the specified color in it using touch and gesture. the user finger finger will move inside the shape to fill the color in it , It has starting point so that it should always start from the right corner until it gets the last corner which should be the ending corner. 
[image: here] is the picture link so that you guys can easily understand what I am trying to say.

in this picture you can see the white space of the center shape , I want to fill it with user finger touch.

I have read to many gesture techniques including the gesture builder , but they are free form drawings , so in my app I have to face do following thing 
 1. To fill under the predefined shape
 2. The shape should be filled in a single way , ie from starting point towards the ending point. 
 3. in other Examples they are drawing on canvas , in my case What should I use ??

Please answer me of my confusions or at least tell me how to do it, Please give me a starting point.